# Anylogic - Setting several delay times in delay block based on source

Tags: service, queue, delay, anylogic

I am beginner in Anylogic. I am modelling post office with queue machine. For example I have 5 different services (source block) and one post counter (delay block). I need to set delay time based on type of service but I dont know how. Could you advise me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you need to have this information on the agent, meaning that you create a variable called delayTime in your agent

In the source you define your time as

```
agent.delayTime=3; //or whatever you want
```

and in the delay, you set as the delay time `agent.delayTime`